# Why I can not use LAG function in this case?

Tags: sql, oracle

Please find the details below:

```sql
Create table TEST_ORDER
(Item VARCHAR2(100),
 Loc VARCHAR2(100),
 Nedddate DATE,
 Qty NUMBER,
 CustQty NUMBER
 )
 
Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/13/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 4.8, 3);
    Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/14/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 3);
    Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/15/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 3);
    Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/16/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 3);
    Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/19/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 3);
    Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/20/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 3);
    Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/21/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 3);
    Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/22/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 3);
    Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/23/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 3);
    Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/26/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 3);
    Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/27/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 3);
    Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/28/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 3);
    Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/29/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 3);
COMMIT;
```

Now we need the logic or output that, standing on current date which is 26th Feb, 2024. This row is having qty = 0.6, custQty =3
qty will be consumed ffrom CustQty, so qty will become 0 (Zero) and CustQty will be 2.4(3-0.6=2.4), in that way it will go backward direction until CustQty gets fully consumed. For previous row(23rd Feb, 2024) qty will become 0 (Zero) and CustQty will be 1.8(2.4-0.6=1.8). For 22nd Feb, 2024
qty will become 0 (Zero) and CustQty will be 1.2(1.8-0.6=1.2). For 21st Feb, 2024 qty will become 0 (Zero) and CustQty will be 0.6(1.2-0.6=0.6).
For 20th Feb, 2024 qty will become 0 (Zero) and CustQty will be 0 (0.6-0.6=0). And we will stop here as Custqty is ZERO now.

So output will be

```
Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/13/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 4.8, 0);
Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/14/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 0);
Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/15/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 0);
Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/16/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 0);
Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/19/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 0);
Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/20/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0, 0);
Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/21/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0, 0.6);
Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/22/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0, 1.2);
Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/23/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0, 1.8);
Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/26/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0, 2.4);
Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/27/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 0);
Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/28/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 0);
Insert into SCPOMGR.TEST_FCSTORDER Values ('ABC', 'XYZ', TO_DATE('2/29/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 0, 0.6, 0);
```

Above one is the first scenario. For second scenario if CustQty does not consumed until First record of the data set, in that case 13th Feb, 2024
then from 27th Feb, 2024(That is the just next record of current date 26th Feb, 2024) record it will consume.

I have tried with Lag function but cannot get the subtract value in runtime. So basically want to know how to do Backward and Forward calculation in
SQL or PL/SQL. If CustQty does not get consumed in backward until first record then it will consume from forward direction.

Thanks,
TSB

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (as text we can copy/paste and execute, **NOT** images); a complete English description of the problem (where does the `updated_custqty` of 2.4 come from?); **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output (again, as text, not images).

Comment: For the second scenario, It would probably be simpler to reduce the `custqty` from the earliest date and then work forward in time rather than trying to start at the current date and work backwards in time until you run out of values and then go back to the present date and work forwards. However, you should not add additional questions to your original question - instead, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and ask about that second scenario there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the problems from the first answer here is a different one using MODEL clause. It is more readable and maintainable. The MODEL clause acts pretty much like excel sheet giving you oportunity to address any row-column/cell. It is both fast and reliable...

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (ITEM, LOC, NEEDDATE, QTY, CUSTQTY) AS
        ( Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-13', 4.8, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-14', 0.6, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-15', 0.6, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-16', 0.6, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-19', 0.6, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-20', 0.6, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-21', 0.6, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-22', 0.6, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-23', 0.6, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-26', 0.6, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-27', 0.6, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-28', 0.6, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-29', 0.6, 7 From Dual
        ),
```

```sql
--   CTE-s to prepare data
  ref_date AS
    ( Select DATE '2024-02-20' "REFDATE" 
      From Dual 
    ),
  stream_down AS
    (   Select      ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By NEEDDATE Desc) "RN", 
                    t.ITEM, t.LOC, t.NEEDDATE, QTY, t.CUSTQTY
        From        tbl t
        Inner Join  ref_date rd ON( 1 = 1 )
        Where       t.NEEDDATE <= rd.REFDATE
    ),
  stream_up AS
    (   Select      ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By NEEDDATE) + 
                                (Select Count(*) "CNT" From stream_down Where ITEM = t.ITEM And LOC = t.LOC) "RN", 
                    t.ITEM, t.LOC, t.NEEDDATE, QTY, t.CUSTQTY
        From        tbl t
        Inner Join  ref_date rd ON( 1 = 1 )
        Where       t.NEEDDATE > rd.REFDATE
        Order By    t.NEEDDATE Desc
    ),
  grid AS
    (   Select      RN, ITEM, LOC, NEEDDATE, QTY, CUSTQTY,
                    Sum(QTY) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By RN Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) "CUMUL_QTY",
                    CUSTQTY - Sum(QTY) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By RN Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) "TOTAL_BALANCE"
        From    ( Select * From stream_down UNION ALL Select * From stream_up )
        Order By    RN
    )
```

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT  ITEM, LOC, NEEDDATE, QTY, CUSTQTY, QTY_NEW, CUSTQTY_REMAINING
FROM    ( Select    RN, ITEM, LOC, NEEDDATE, QTY, CUSTQTY,
                    Cast(Null as Number) "QTY_NEW", Cast(Null As Number) "CUSTQTY_REMAINING", 
                    CUMUL_QTY, TOTAL_BALANCE
          From      grid
          Order By  RN
        )
    MODEL   Partition By ( ITEM, LOC )
            Dimension By ( RN )
            Measures     ( NEEDDATE, QTY, CUSTQTY, QTY_NEW, CUMUL_QTY, CUSTQTY_REMAINING, TOTAL_BALANCE )
    RULES  (  CUMUL_QTY[ANY] = Case When Nvl(CUMUL_QTY[CV()], 0) <= CUSTQTY[CV()] + QTY[CV()] Then CUMUL_QTY[CV()] End, 
              CUSTQTY_REMAINING[ANY] = Case When TOTAL_BALANCE[CV()] < 0 Then Null
                                       Else Case When Nvl(CUMUL_QTY[CV()], 0) <= CUSTQTY[CV()] + QTY[CV()] 
                                                 Then CUSTQTY[CV()] - Nvl(CUMUL_QTY[CV()], 0) 
                                            End
                                       End,
              QTY_NEW[ANY] = Case When TOTAL_BALANCE[CV()] < 0 And ABS(TOTAL_BALANCE[CV()]) > QTY[CV()] Then QTY[CV()]
                                  When TOTAL_BALANCE[CV()] < 0 And ABS(TOTAL_BALANCE[CV()]) <= QTY[CV()] Then QTY[CV()] - (TOTAL_BALANCE[CV()] + QTY[CV()])
                             Else Case When QTY[CV()] <= Nvl(CUSTQTY_REMAINING[CV()], 0) +  QTY[CV()]  Then 0 
                                  Else QTY[CV()] - CUSTQTY_REMAINING[CV()]
                                  End
                             End
           )
ORDER BY   ITEM, LOC, NEEDDATE Desc
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
ITEM LOC NEEDDATE        QTY    CUSTQTY    QTY_NEW CUSTQTY_REMAINING
---- --- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------------
ABC  XYZ 29.02.24         ,6          7         ,6                          
ABC  XYZ 28.02.24         ,6          7         ,6                          
ABC  XYZ 27.02.24         ,6          7         ,6                          
ABC  XYZ 26.02.24         ,6          7         ,6                          
ABC  XYZ 23.02.24         ,6          7         ,6                          
ABC  XYZ 22.02.24         ,6          7         ,6                          
ABC  XYZ 21.02.24         ,6          7         ,6                          
ABC  XYZ 20.02.24         ,6          7          0               6,4
ABC  XYZ 19.02.24         ,6          7          0               5,8
ABC  XYZ 16.02.24         ,6          7          0               5,2
ABC  XYZ 15.02.24         ,6          7          0               4,6
ABC  XYZ 14.02.24         ,6          7          0                 4
ABC  XYZ 13.02.24        4,8          7         ,8                       */
```

... more about MODEL close [here](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm)

Comment: @d r I have checked it. 9 scenarios are working fine with that. You are absolute genius. KUDOS to you and your effort. How unbelievable knowledge, patience  you have really appreciable. Thanks a ton. Is there any way to connect with you (i.e. Linkedin, twitter or whatever) to learn from you? Again I am saying you are AMAZING.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SUM` analytic function to get a running total, not `LAG`:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       LEAST(
         GREATEST(
           COALESCE(
             SUM(
               CASE WHEN needdate < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1 THEN qty END
             ) OVER (PARTITION BY item, loc ORDER BY needdate DESC) - custqty,
             qty
           ),
           0
         ),
         qty
       ) AS updated_qty,
       CASE
       WHEN needdate > TRUNC(SYSDATE)
       THEN NULL
       WHEN SUM(
              CASE WHEN needdate < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1 THEN qty END
            ) OVER (
              PARTITION BY item, loc
              ORDER BY needdate DESC
              ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
            ) >= custqty
       THEN NULL
       ELSE GREATEST(
              custqty
              - SUM(
                CASE WHEN needdate < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1 THEN qty END
              ) OVER (PARTITION BY item, loc ORDER BY needdate DESC),
              0
           )
       END AS updated_custqty
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (item, loc, needdate, qty, custqty) AS
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-13', 4.8, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-14', 0.6, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-15', 0.6, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-16', 0.6, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-19', 0.6, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-20', 0.6, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-21', 0.6, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-22', 0.6, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-23', 0.6, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-26', 0.6, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-27', 0.6, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-28', 0.6, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-29', 0.6, 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ITEM | LOC | NEEDDATE | QTY | CUSTQTY | UPDATED_QTY | UPDATED_CUSTQTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | XYZ | 2024-02-29 00:00:00 | .6 | 3 | .6 | *null* |
| ABC | XYZ | 2024-02-28 00:00:00 | .6 | 3 | .6 | *null* |
| ABC | XYZ | 2024-02-27 00:00:00 | .6 | 3 | .6 | *null* |
| ABC | XYZ | 2024-02-26 00:00:00 | .6 | 3 | 0 | 2.4 |
| ABC | XYZ | 2024-02-23 00:00:00 | .6 | 3 | 0 | 1.8 |
| ABC | XYZ | 2024-02-22 00:00:00 | .6 | 3 | 0 | 1.2 |
| ABC | XYZ | 2024-02-21 00:00:00 | .6 | 3 | 0 | .6 |
| ABC | XYZ | 2024-02-20 00:00:00 | .6 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| ABC | XYZ | 2024-02-19 00:00:00 | .6 | 3 | .6 | *null* |
| ABC | XYZ | 2024-02-16 00:00:00 | .6 | 3 | .6 | *null* |
| ABC | XYZ | 2024-02-15 00:00:00 | .6 | 3 | .6 | *null* |
| ABC | XYZ | 2024-02-14 00:00:00 | .6 | 3 | .6 | *null* |
| ABC | XYZ | 2024-02-13 00:00:00 | 4.8 | 3 | 4.8 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pAQL5nml)

Comment: Thanks it is working. but what about second scenario any idea? if my backward direction reach first record and we still have CustQty left we need to go forward direction from next record of Sysdate.

Comment: @TSB For a (fundamentally) different question, you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) rather than trying to append something onto the question that was not originally asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Combination of Case expressions and analytic functions - some with and some without windowing clause (rows between ...) - could do the job.
Try it like here this should work for both your issues. Here the inner query, starting at reference date, goes backwards and outer query takes care of remainings (if any) going forewards from refdate...

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (ITEM, LOC, NEEDDATE, QTY, CUSTQTY) AS
        ( Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-13', 4.8, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-14', 0.6, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-15', 0.6, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-16', 0.6, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-19', 0.6, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-20', 0.6, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-21', 0.6, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-22', 0.6, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-23', 0.6, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-26', 0.6, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-27', 0.6, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-28', 0.6, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 'ABC', 'XYZ', DATE '2024-02-29', 0.6, 3 From Dual
        ),
```

... here is a reference date cte (it could be SYSDATE or whatever) to be used as starting point to go backwards or forewards

```sql
  ref_date AS
    ( Select DATE '2024-02-26' "REFDATE" From Dual )
```

```sql
--    M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT ITEM, LOC, NEEDDATE, QTY, CUSTQTY, 
  CASE When NEEDDATE > REFDATE And Sum(QTY) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By NEEDDATE Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row ) >= CUSTQTY + QTY
                     Then QTY
  ELSE Nvl(Case When NEEDDATE <= REFDATE OR Min(Case When NEEDDATE <= REFDATE Then Nvl(CUSTQTY_REMAINING, 0) End) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC) = 0 Then QTY_NEW
            
            When Min(Case When NEEDDATE <= REFDATE Then CUSTQTY_REMAINING End) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC) - 
                  Sum(Case When NEEDDATE > REFDATE Then QTY End) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By NEEDDATE Desc Rows Between Current Row And Unbounded Following) >= 0
             Then 0
             
             When Sum(QTY) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By NEEDDATE Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row ) >= CUSTQTY 
             Then (QTY - (Sum(Case When NEEDDATE > REFDATE Then QTY End) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By NEEDDATE Desc Rows Between Current Row And Unbounded Following) -
                          Min(Case When NEEDDATE <= REFDATE Then CUSTQTY_REMAINING End) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC)
                         ) 
                  ) *-1 + QTY
       End
        * Case When Sum(QTY) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By NEEDDATE Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding ) < CUSTQTY Then 1 Else 0 End, QTY) 
    END "QTY_NEW", 
       --
       Case When NEEDDATE <= REFDATE Then CUSTQTY_REMAINING
       Else     Case When Min(Case When NEEDDATE <= REFDATE Then CUSTQTY_REMAINING End) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC) - 
                          Sum(Case When NEEDDATE > REFDATE Then QTY End) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By NEEDDATE Desc Rows Between Current Row And Unbounded Following) >= 0
                     Then Min(Case When NEEDDATE <= REFDATE Then CUSTQTY_REMAINING End) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC) - 
                          Sum(Case When NEEDDATE > REFDATE Then QTY End) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By NEEDDATE Desc Rows Between Current Row And Unbounded Following)
                     When Min(Case When NEEDDATE <= REFDATE Then CUSTQTY_REMAINING End) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC) - 
                          Sum(Case When NEEDDATE > REFDATE Then QTY End) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By NEEDDATE Desc Rows Between Current Row And Unbounded Following) < 0
                     Then   Null
                End
       End "CUSTQTY_REMAINING"

FROM  ( Select      ITEM, LOC, NEEDDATE, QTY, CUSTQTY, rf.REFDATE, 
               Case When Sum(Case When NEEDDATE <= rf.REFDATE Then QTY End) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By NEEDDATE Desc) <= CUSTQTY 
                    Then  Case When Sum(Case When NEEDDATE <= rf.REFDATE Then QTY End) 
                                        Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By NEEDDATE Desc
                                             Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) <= CUSTQTY
                              Then 0
                          Else QTY
                          End 
                End "QTY_NEW", 
                    Case When Sum(Case When NEEDDATE <= rf.REFDATE Then QTY End) 
                                  Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By NEEDDATE Desc
                                       Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) <= CUSTQTY
                        Then CUSTQTY - 
                             Sum(Case When NEEDDATE <= rf.REFDATE Then QTY End) 
                                 Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By NEEDDATE Desc
                                      Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) 
                    End "CUSTQTY_REMAINING"
        From        tbl
        Inner Join  ref_date rf ON(1 = 1)
        Order By    NEEDDATE Desc
      )
  Order By    NEEDDATE Desc
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :   (for CUSTQTY = 3)
ITEM LOC NEEDDATE        QTY    CUSTQTY    QTY_NEW CUSTQTY_REMAINING
---- --- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------------
ABC  XYZ 29.02.24         ,6          3         ,6                 
ABC  XYZ 28.02.24         ,6          3         ,6                 
ABC  XYZ 27.02.24         ,6          3         ,6                 
ABC  XYZ 26.02.24         ,6          3          0               2,4
ABC  XYZ 23.02.24         ,6          3          0               1,8
ABC  XYZ 22.02.24         ,6          3          0               1,2
ABC  XYZ 21.02.24         ,6          3          0                ,6               
ABC  XYZ 20.02.24         ,6          3          0                 0
ABC  XYZ 19.02.24         ,6          3         ,6                          
ABC  XYZ 16.02.24         ,6          3         ,6                          
ABC  XYZ 15.02.24         ,6          3         ,6                          
ABC  XYZ 14.02.24         ,6          3         ,6                          
ABC  XYZ 13.02.24        4,8          3        4,8                     */
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :   (for CUSTQTY = 12.4)
ITEM LOC NEEDDATE        QTY    CUSTQTY    QTY_NEW CUSTQTY_REMAINING
---- --- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------------
ABC  XYZ 29.02.24         ,6       12,4          0                ,4               
ABC  XYZ 28.02.24         ,6       12,4          0                 1
ABC  XYZ 27.02.24         ,6       12,4          0               1,6  -- 2nd go up if there is reamining CUSTQTY
ABC  XYZ 26.02.24         ,6       12,4          0              11,8  -- 1st go down from refdate
ABC  XYZ 23.02.24         ,6       12,4          0              11,2
ABC  XYZ 22.02.24         ,6       12,4          0              10,6
ABC  XYZ 21.02.24         ,6       12,4          0                10
ABC  XYZ 20.02.24         ,6       12,4          0               9,4
ABC  XYZ 19.02.24         ,6       12,4          0               8,8
ABC  XYZ 16.02.24         ,6       12,4          0               8,2
ABC  XYZ 15.02.24         ,6       12,4          0               7,6
ABC  XYZ 14.02.24         ,6       12,4          0                 7
ABC  XYZ 13.02.24        4,8       12,4          0               2,2   */
```

Comment: Thanks @d r, it is fully working for backward-forward direction. But not full proof for backward direction only. Because for CustQty = 3 for 27,28,29 Feb we are getting qty_new 0, -0.6 and -1.2 respectively. Let me see why this is happening. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TSB Try to add  condition to the outer Case in outer query for QTY_NEW column the one after Nvl. Add OR Min() Over() (from inner csse) = 0

Comment: @TSB Fixed it. There was OR condition missing in outer query's QTY_NEW column Case expression.

Comment: @d r it is working perfectly. Thanks for your time and help. You are legend!!!

Comment: @d r still it is not working for some cases. It is giving minus QTY_NEW.

Comment: @TSB going up or down? I could try to simulate it...

Comment: @d r Forward direction. For example 13-02-2024 is related and custqty is 7. Even some point it should show 0.6-0.4=0.2, but it is showing 0.4. And after that it is showing minus value for Qty_new

Comment: 13-02-2024 is refdate. type in my previous comment.

Comment: @TSB Just updated the code. Try it now!

Comment: @d r, Thanks for your help!!! above criteria is working but previous one is not working. If we put refdate as 20-FEB-2024 and custqty as 7 then on 13-FEB-2024  qty_new should be 4.8-2.8=2 but it is showing 4.8(That means it is not consuming at all from 13-FEB-2024) and it is going to 21-FEB-2024(Forward direction).

Comment: @TSB sorry, will have to rewrite it from scratch uusing MODEL clause....

Comment: @d r okay. Let me check then how MODEL works.

Comment: @TSB Posted a completely new answer using MODEL clause, hope that would fit your needs... Please check it ...